# split up a compound column into something I can pivot

Tags: pandas

I've got a dataframe that's similar to below:

```
Name|Gender|Selections
May |Female|Bar, Que
Joe |Male  |Foo, Bar, Que
Sue |Female|NaN
Pat |Male  |Foo
```

The Selections row contains a comma-deliminated *string* (edit: made it clearer it's a string) of discrete options. I have a list containing all possible options.

I'd like to end up with a dataframe that I can pivot (or similar) so I can view the count of options vs gender:

```
      |Foo|Bar|Que
Male  | 2 | 1 | 1
Female| 0 | 1 | 1
```

I figured the first step would be to convert Selections into multiple columns Foo Bar and Que, where each row was true or false:

```
options=["Foo", "Bar", "Que"]
for option in options:
    df[option] = data["Selections"].str.contains(option, regex=False)
---
Name|Gender|Selections   |Foo  |Bar  |Que 
May |Female|Bar, Que     |false|true |true
Joe |Male  |Foo, Bar, Que|true |true |true
Sue |Female|NaN          |false|false|false
Pat |Male  |Foo          |true |false|false
```

...however pivoting with `columns=options` results in stacked column headers, which I'll spare you.

How do I go from that first table, to that second table?

At this point I don't really care about speed, it's a small dataframe and it'll be infrequently parsed.

(also I'm inexperienced at pandas, so forgive the vague question heading. I don't really know the name of what I'm asking for!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create index by `Gender` column, get [`str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) and last aggregate `sum` per index:

```
df = df.set_index('Gender')['Selections'].str.get_dummies(', ').sum(level=0)
print (df)
        Bar  Foo  Que
Gender               
Female    1    0    1
Male      1    2    1
```

Comment: thanks! are there advantages to the second approach? cuz it seems longer with more dependencies.

Comment: @tenpn - It is faster, but depends of real data. Added timings to answer.

Comment: this isn't quite working for me, because I think my Selections field is a string, not categorical. I don't think I was explicit about that tho. My end result has a column for every letter of the alphabet!

Comment: @tenpn - so solution is simplier, `df = df.set_index('Gender')['Selections'].str.get_dummies(', ').max(level=0)`

Comment: closer! but each row is only 1 or 0. I wanted to count how many women selected Bar (_another_ thing I wasn't explicit about, apologies). I tried replacing max() with count() but that gives me just the Options, with the total row count of the df.

Comment: @tenpn - So need `sum` - `df = df.set_index('Gender')['Selections'].str.get_dummies(', ').sum(level=0)`